# Is it correct sampling procedure?

Tags: statistics, sampling

I have to build a model to predict binary variable, for example, V1. The general population have the 18% frequency that V1 = 1. Also, I can get the sample with size < 600 rows only. What sampling procedure is more correct?
1. Random sampling with fixed frequency = 18% (V1=1).
2. Random sampling with fixed frequency 50% (V1=1).

I think the second procedure is totally incorrect, but dont know how I can explain it to my colleagues. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to accomplish.

If you want to estimate the proportion of the population with V1=1, then you want a random sample of the population.

If V1 is known and you want to directly study the *effect* of V1 on some other variable(s), then it might be worth sampling with frequency 50% so the design is balanced.

If you're interested in other variables beyond V1 and you're *not* just directly studying the effect of V1, then you should sample completely at random (or with 18% frequency V1) to prevent bias.  In a simple example, if you're interested in the proportion of another variable V2=1, and there's a possibility of a relationship between V1 and V2, then over-representing your sample with individuals such that V1=1 will result in a biased estimate.

Let's say you want to estimate the proportion of the population with lung disease.  If 18% of the population are smokers, then sampling 50% smokers and 50% non-smokers would lead to an *over*-estimation of lung disease.  You'd be better off with a random sample, or at least 18% / 82% sampling.

However, if you want to compare the proportion of those with lung disease *between smokers and non-smokers*, then you would want your study to include near-equal samples of smokers and non-smokers.

If you're doing something more complex than this - say, V1 is your variable of interest and you have a logistic regression model (or something similar) such that you're investigating the effects of multiple variables *on* V1, then it may not matter as much.  In this case, a 50/50 split MIGHT yield better results ... but I might be concerned about the effects of un-observed variables if one portion of the population is systematically over-represented.

Don't know if this helps - I'd recommend consulting with a statistician and describing the specifics of your study.

Comment: Thank you for good comment!
Yeap, you are right, My next step will be the building logistic regression with dependent variable V1. So Im pretty confused now what procedure is better for this. I dont like 50/50 sampling, dont know why.

Comment: V1 - it is a variable describing a human, when 1 - he is violator, when 0 - clean-living. The others variables - some sociodemographic data.